# What is the name for the the habit of reciting song titles or clichés when anyone says the first few words?

Tags: single-word-requests

I like literary and cultural references, but I can enjoy them without proving that I get the reference by reciting the entire title or quote.

I know that explicitly sharing social experience is the modern poosking, but I find it gauche. I'm not elitist; I'm just introverted.

So, is there a name for the compulsion to announce and explain references, subtle or otherwise?

Comment: Showboating? Verbal twerking?

Comment: No, "showboating" is showing-off. And twerking can mean anything these days. I mean, the need to show everyone that you get the joke, really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"An annoying habit"** comes to mind.  I also wonder if it is a bit of a compulsion so maybe the term **"compulsive trivia-reciting"** can be adopted for this trait.  I also know people with this habit and after the 50-millionth Elvis impersonation for "thank you, thank you very much", you can imagine how it is received.

Answer (score 2):

There's no common term for that that I've encountered. If there was, I'd have probably heard it, because this describes my own behavior fairly well, at least with music. I trained my brain in childhood to play a local radio contest. The contest is over, but the training remains.

My wife does the same with Shakespeare. If you say a line of The Bard's around her, you're most likely gonna hear the next line. Just about any engineer I know is liable to pull the same trick on you if you quote from Monty Python's Holy Grail or Princess Bride.

Comment: Still with the Holy Grail refs? That was driving folks nuts even back in the 1980's.

Answer (score 1):

Think referential fits the bill

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This site works best when answers are supported with explanations as well as suitable references or links. For additional guidance, please visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).